# Central superscripts and subscripts with any letter or symbol

Tags: katex

I'm trying to write the following in Notion (using KaTeX library):

[image]

The closest thing I've got is with this code:

```
L_{DNI} = \left( \text{U}_{i=1}^{8} \right) L_A
```

[image]

I would like to do the same with others letters like A,B or the intersection symbol(∩). Any idea?

Edit:

I've found the solution before this post by myselft but i want to share with the community.

Just using underset and overset can be done easily:

```
L_{DNI} = \left( \overset{8}{\underset{i=1}{\text{U}}} \right) L_A
```

[image]

You can replace the text field section with anything:

[image] [image] [image]

If you try with Unicode symbols doesn't work well:

[image]

Comment: Remember (1) `katex` is off topic here, (2) `katex` is limited in what it is capable of, so even if a latex splution exists it might not be applicable for `katex`.

Comment: @dailef You're right. It is like MathJaX.

Comment: @daleif Yeah, I know KaTeX is limited but is the only library that Notion support. Respect the off topic, I should delete the Katex tag or just is not a valid question here?

Comment: @Sebastiano AFAIK mathjax supports more than katex

Comment: @daleif I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[L_{\textup{DNI}} = \left( \bigcup^{8}_{i=1} \right) L_A\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}


\begin{document}
\[L_{\textup{DNI}} = \left( \bigcup^{8}_{i=1} L_{D}\right) L_A\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}


\begin{document}
\[L_{\textup{DNI}} = \left( \bigcap^{8}_{i=1} L_{D}\right) L_A\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, thanks! Your solution is more simple. I accept your response